# Filter for SearchView in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, filter, android-arrayadapter, searchview

**Android environment** 
**kotlin_version** = '1.3.20' 
**compileSdkVersion** 28

I have an **adapter** of type **ArrayAdapter<String>** which is represented as **ListView** in the app activity. How to get the filter for SearchView to work?

**Activity.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView">
        ...

</android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>


<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        ...
 />
```

**Activity.kt**

```
   ...

         searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

                    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {

                        adapter.filter.filter(newText)

                        return true
                    }

                    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
                        // task HERE
                        return false
                    }

                })

    ...
```

So the **setOnQueryTextListener**() is working and even the **adapter** is working properly, but I'm unable to get the filter working.

Comment: Honestly, the best way is to use RecyclerView, and ditch SearchView for your own code ;) but I know that's not exactly a complete answer, hence why it is a comment. I don't think SearchView *ever* suited my requirements.

Comment: Can you post your adapter code ?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thanks for your suggestion. I'll try using RecyclerView next time.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

The solution to this problem was rather in the code scope definition itself. For people who might stumble across similar situation, plz make sure to check the **searchView.setOnQueryTextListener()** & make sure to keep it out of any loops which you might be using for feeding the list for adapter. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

After the filter statement.

Comment: Thanks but it works without notifyDataSetChanged() as well. :) The problem was with the entire block of setOnQueryTextListener() itself. It needed to be outside the scope of a loop I was using to fill my list.

Answer (score 0):

Notify the **adapter** for the data change :

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

                override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
                    adapter.filter.filter(newText)
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    return true
                }

                override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
                    return false
                }

            })
```

Comment: Thanks but it works without notifyDataSetChanged() as well. :) The problem was with the entire block of setOnQueryTextListener() itself. It needed to be outside the scope of a loop I was using to fill my list.